# Why doesnt self made slope function work

Tags: javascript, html, processing, p5.js

Why doesnt this display a ball moving at a slant?

I am trying to get a slope function to allow this ball to move across the screen given two points and a current x but it doesnt work.

this is p5.js: http://p5js.org

```
function graphY(num,cHI){
    var GsetR = cHI-num;
    return(GsetR);
};

function slope(x1,y1,x2,y2,ex){
    var gg1 = x2-x1;
    var gg2 = y2-y2;
    var ggs = gg2/gg1;
    return(graphY(ggs*ex));
};

function setup() {
    createCanvas(1000,650);   
}

var slipX= 100;
var slipY= 500;

function draw() {
  background(204);
  fill(0,0,0);

  ellipse(slipX,slipY,20,20);
  slipY = slope(100,500,200,400,slipX);
  slipX++;
  text(slipY,20,20);  
}
```

If this is not how I am supposed to do this. (I saw something about vectors but diddnt understand) then how do I do it? (It being moving an object from one point to another on the shortest path possible.)

Comment: Have you tried [debugging](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) your code? Which line of code is behaving differently from what you expected?

Comment: yes once i call the slope function for slipY it breaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some simple problems in your code that can be solved by stepping through and looking at each function. Using the debugger, or placing `console.log()` statements in strategic locations is a good way to figure out what's wrong. For example if you do this to your `slope` function you'll spot your mistake:

```
function slope(x1,y1,x2,y2,ex){
    var gg1 = x2-x1;
    var gg2 = y2-y2;
    var ggs = gg2/gg1;
    console.log(ggs)    // <-- why is ggs always zero?? 
                        //     Maybe a typo in gg2 (should probably be y2 - y1)
    return(graphY(ggs*ex));
};
```

or:

```
function graphY(num,cHI){
    var GsetR = cHI-num;
    console.log(GsetR)  // <-- why is this NaN
    return(GsetR);
};
```

`graphY()` takes two arguments: `num` and `cHI`. But you are calling it with one in `slope()`. That makes the return value of `graphY()` `NaN` (not a number).

These are mostly just typos so this thread will probably get closed at some point, but I hope this gets you pointed in the right direction.